# flutter huawei push notification from onesignal

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

when I set one signal setup and app gallery on my flutter code it said that the user is not subscribed and the user didn't remove or clear data any idea how to do it?

and this is how i call one signal.

```
await OneSignal.shared.setAppId('appid');

  await OneSignal.shared
      .promptUserForPushNotificationPermission()
      .then((accepted) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('accepted');
  });
```

Comment: You can try exiting your app and launching the app again. I tried OneSignal official demo code (on Github) in May 2022. I found a similar issue. It should be OneSignal compatibility issue. If this cannot be resolved, could you please share your log or screenshot of the issue?